# include javascript file based on the URL

Tags: php, header-files

i have an application in which i have created a `header.php` which is obviously common for all the pages in the app which i include on top of every other page. This header file contains the `html` head tags and `DOCTYPE` declaration etc and some common JS and CSS files needed for every page. But there are some specific files which i want to include depending on the page.

Now, how do i include a specific JS or CSS file based on the url from which the `header.php` is requested.

I tried to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` at the top of header file to fetch the url but it did not work.

Please suggest with the best technique that should be used in this situation.

**Sample Code**

`header.php`

```
 <?php
 include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/functions.php");
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My APP</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir" />
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<?php
if($url == "teachers.php"){
echo "<script src='js/teachers.js'></script>";
   }  
?>

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Show some code. "it did not work" is not enough.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I've edited to include the code

Comment: Do you request `teachers.php` in your browser? And how does that look?

Comment: Did you try to `echo` `$url` to see what it actually contains?

Comment: yes, i request `teachers.php`. Well, its has its own HTML code and on top i've included this header file

Comment: @BartFriederichs Well, i'm sorry, i did not. Now when i did, i realised that it contained the directory name too and i was just trying to include the JS tag based on the file requested. SIlly me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array you are looking for is the superglobal [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). It has all that info. More specifically: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gives the complete path, including slashes and any GET request. In your case (if `teachers.php` is in your server's root, and you don't GET anything), it will hold `/teachers.php`, and you are comparing against `teachers.php`.

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` gets the **executing** script, which is what you seem to be looking for.

You could use [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to filter the path out:

```
$url = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

By the way, @hendyanto's solution is also good. It is certainly robust against filename changes.

Comment: In my opinion, u create the array or object, like $css = array('uri' => array('css1.css', 'css2.css') ...)
And make the function that load the spec css or js with the suggested request_uri property

Comment: Well, its still not working. what i am doing is that on top of the header file before the `DOCTYPE` declaration i'm storing the request_uri array value in a variable and then based on that i'm trying to include the JS tag

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable on the page that will include header.php, later, check the variable inside the header.php to determine what to do.

Example

> in home.php (sample page that will call header.php)

```
<?php
$page_code = "home";
include ("header.php");

/*Rest of your code*/

?>
```

> in header.php

```
<?php
switch ($page_code) {
case 'home':
    echo "include js and css here..";
    break;

case 'profile':
    echo "include js and css here..";
    break;

default:
    # code...
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks man, as @bart mentioned, ur code is indeed very robust.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's perfect or not, but i use it in my applications

anypage.php

```
<?php
$js= "path/jstoinclude.js";
include "header.php";
?>
```

in header.php

```
<?php
//your code
if(isset($js)){
echo "<script src='".$js."'></script>";
}
?>
```

in this way you can include separate js, css files to different pages